# Search across sites and sub-site lists based on Content type REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-rest-api

I have multiple subsites and each subsite has a list called "Vidoes". it has a content type called "Video Fields". I would like to search based on the content types above using  search api with rest. It should result all the items present in all the sites and subsistes.
Basically the user will give the meta data as input

Can any one help on the same

Comment: Find your content type internal name and use "SPContentType=[contentTypeName]" in your query

Comment: What is reason for using REST rather than default Search? Are you planning to use the result in code?

Comment: Actually i want to fetch them in sharepoint Grid and write a jquery filter

Answer (score 1):

REST API:

```
    var searchApi = '/_api/search/query?querytext=%27ContentType:"Video Fields"'
    var selectedParameter = '&trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=%27500%27&selectproperties=%27NameOWSTEXT%27';
    var searchQuery = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl +searchApi + ' %27' + selectedParameter
    var query = "";
    $.ajax({
        url: searchQuery,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        async: false,
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) 
        {
           console.log(data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results);

        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks DeepMala . I was able to search based on content type. But why can't i see the Site Columns assoicated with that content type. For example i have Title,VideoUrl,VideoId assoicated with that content type. But i can't see those Items. Can you plse help in this regard

Comment: You need specify these site columns managed properties under selectproperties parameter

Comment: Actually when i use select properties it is returning 'Null' Even though my list has data for that field. Any idea on the same

Comment: I think I am missing the OWSTEXT. it is working fine

Comment: How can we sort by ListItemID. This is my last question

Comment: &sortlist=%27ListItemIDOwsText:ascending%27&selectproperties=

Comment: It says Invalid parameter: SortList

Comment: Make sure the name of Managed property is valid and is sortable

Comment: Managed Property is correct only . Because i can see the value for it in my Select Properties. So basically it is nothing but my ID Column of an Item